# Pandas groupby multiple columns, but need show unique value in a column after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, jupyter

I have a dataframe like the one below:

```
    Supplier_number Supplier_name   Supply_cat  USD
0   111               A             Cat_1        1
1   221               B             Cat_1        2
2   222               B             Cat_1        3
3   331               C             Cat_1        4
4   332               C             Cat_2        5
5   441               D             Cat_1        6
6   551               E             Cat_2        7
7   552               E             Cat_1        8
```

I then run the below lines and return the df below:

```
df_2a = df.groupby(['Supplier_number','Supplier_name', 'Supply_cat', ], as_index = False).sum().sort_values('USD')

    Supplier_number Supplier_name   Supply_cat  USD
0   111             A               Cat_1       1
1   221             B               Cat_1       2
2   222             B               Cat_1       3
3   331             C               Cat_1       4
4   332             C               Cat_2       5
5   441             D               Cat_1       6
6   551             E               Cat_2       7
7   552             E               Cat_1       8
```

However the df i would like to obtain is like the one below

```
Supplier_number Supplier_name   Supply_cat     USD
0   111             A               Cat_1       1
**1 221             B               Cat_1       5
2   222**                                       
3   331             C               Cat_1       4
4   332             C               Cat_2       5
5   441             D               Cat_1       6
6   551             E               Cat_2       7
7   552             E               Cat_1       8
```

The logic: Same Supplier Name, Same Supply Category, Multiple Supplier Number - Group the Supplier Name and Supply Category, sum the USD, but leave the Supplier Number intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the DataFrame would have the same size as the original. So we can calculate USD first and then put duplicate cells in `NaN`.
We can try with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) + `sum`
to get the `USD` column. Then you can [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) duplicates with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

```
columns_group = ['Supplier_name', 'Supply_cat']
mask_columns = df.columns.difference(['Supplier_number'])
df['USD'] = df.groupby(columns_group)['USD'].transform('sum')
df[mask_columns] = df[mask_columns].mask(df.duplicated(columns_group))

#if you want blanks instead NaN
#df[mask_columns] = df[mask_columns].mask(df.duplicated(columns_group), '')


print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Supplier_number Supplier_name Supply_cat  USD
0              111             A      Cat_1  1.0
1              221             B      Cat_1  5.0
2              222           NaN        NaN  NaN
3              331             C      Cat_1  4.0
4              332             C      Cat_2  5.0
5              441             D      Cat_1  6.0
6              551             E      Cat_2  7.0
7              552             E      Cat_1  8.0
```